# 重複するカスタムテンプレート名が存在する場合の動作について

Tags: wordpress

Template Nameが同じテンプレートファイルが2つあった場合、
どういった基準で一方のテンプレートファイルを呼び出すのでしょうか？
更新日時とかですか？

Answer (score 1):

単純には、一番最初に見つけたファイルを使います。
検索による読み出し順番は、phpでは グロブ関数により決まります。https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.glob.php